# Datastore modeling hierarchy for efficient queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm really confused regarding datastore hierarchy and how to model my app.

My app will have users.

The data would have this particular hierarchy:

The User will own a Tournament.

Tournament ( properties: geodata )

Inside tournament the user will add one or more Teams.

Inside Teams the user will add info on a daily basis.

For example:

```
Team: Hawks  
Concept: Equipment  
String: Buy t-shirts  
Number: 11  
Number (price) : 15
```

Does something like this makes sense?

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pass = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email= db.StringProperty()

class Tournament(db.Model):
    name  = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    place = db.GeoPt()
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(User) 

class Teams(db.Model):
    belongs_to_tournament = db.ReferenceProperty(Tournament)
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    players = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)

class DailyInfo(db.Model):
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    concept = db.StringListProperty()
    info    = db.StringProperty()
    number  = db.IntegerProperty()
    price   = db.IntegerProperty()
    team    = db.ReferenceProperty(Teams)
```

Is this model done right or should I also add ancestor paths? Would I be able to query on this for displaying each users corresponding info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you model you havn't defined `indexed=False`, Do you required indexed on each property of each db?

Like here,

```
class Tournament(db.Model):
   name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
   place = db.GeoPt()

class Teams(db.Model):
   belongs_to_tournament = db.ReferenceProperty(Tournament, collection_name =  'tournament_teams')
   name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
   players = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
   price = db.FloatProperty(indexed=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I would update my code. I finally got adviced that I should be using parents other than reference property.